# Signal R ASP.Net (Starts pending when server access the application)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, signalr

We published an application in a laptop that act as a server, then access the application by other pc through wlan, Signal R works when the client's pc (Multiple Clients) access the application. But when the server's pc starts to access the application, Signal R starts pending.

Code on startup (Receives Update):

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    $.connection.hub.stop();
    $.connection.hub.start();
}); // fixed for mobile browsers

$.connection.myHub.client.getUpdate = function (message) {
    console.log(message);
    getInventoryInformation();
}
```

Code on sending updates (Triggered by click event)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/Restaurant/SalePackageIng",
    data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
    beforeSend: function () {
        $(".overlay").show();
    },
    success: function () {
        $.connection.myHub.server.getUpdate("Current Inventory Updated!");
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("Oops! Something went wrong. 562");
    }
});
```

We conclude that every time the server's pc access the application signal r starts pending.